# HTML and CSS --- margin Problems

Tags: html, css

If you place a margin-top on the first box (red_box) it  pulls or affects the containing box (container). Why?

```css
.red_box {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;`
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px
}

.green_box {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red_box">
    red box
  </div>
  <div class="green_box">
    green box
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin.

You can prevent it with an [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Foverflow) rule on the `.container`:

```css
.red_box {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;`
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.green_box {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden; /* <-- this prevents margin collapsing */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red_box">
    red box
  </div>
  <div class="green_box">
    green box
  </div>
</div>
```